# `$("selector").is(":visible")` doesn't work within a modal (bootstrap modal)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I use `$("selector").is(":visible")` to check the visibility of an element a lot.

However, when working with an element within a modal(bootstrap modal), this simply malfunctions.

Eventhough I find a way to use `$("selector").css("display")` as a makeshift, this is still a problem worth a solution.

Please, check this [jsiddle page](https://jsfiddle.net/jn111sum/2/) out to see more relevant infomations about this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because your modal is not alredy displayed when you execute your code. There is an animation. Here is the modified code to prove that point. You could use Modal events to accomplish what you want :

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(labelError.is(":visible"));
    console.log(labelError.css("display"));
    labelError.show();

    console.log(labelError.css("display"));
    console.log(labelError.is(":visible"));
},500);
```

See the modified jsfidle page here : https://jsfiddle.net/pbjd2bz6/

Answer (score 0):

Since Bootstrap 3.0, we can use **on('shown.bs.modal'**, function (e) {

See JsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jn111sum/4/

```
$( "#generator" ).on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var labelError=$("#phrasesError");
        $("#phrasesError").fadeOut();
    console.log("this is where the useful infos begin");
    console.log(labelError.is(":visible"));
    console.log(labelError.css("display"));
    labelError.show();
    console.log(labelError.css("display"));
    console.log(labelError.is(":visible"));
});
```

Hope that helps